# Inflection points on elliptic curves over a field of characteristic 2

Tags: elliptic-curves

I'm looking at the elliptic curve $C:={\cal Z}(XY^2+ZX^2+YZ^2)$ in the field $k:=\overline{\mathbb{F}_2}$. I want to prove that this curve has 9 inflection points. Since the characteristic of $k$ is 2, I cannot use the Hessian determinant, which is always zero in this case. I have also shown that ${\cal Z}(X)\cap C$, ${\cal Z}(Y)\cap C$ and ${\cal Z}(Z)\cap C$ aren't inflection points. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you plug in $Z= aX +bY$ and impose that it gives a cube $(\alpha X + \beta Y)^3$ ? Can you solve that for $(\beta:\alpha:1)$ ?

Comment: Compute the Hessian determinant as though the equation had integer coefficients, remove the extra factors of two and then reduce.  You get the equation $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + xyz$, cutting out the inflection points on $C$.

Comment: @MP: that's neat! does this always work? why?

Comment: @MP: In which field extension are the inflection points, found by solving the equation, defined?

Comment: If you just want to know that there are 9 inflection points, why don't you just say that they form a torsor under the group of points of order 3, isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/3)^2$?

Comment: @abx Thanks! There is one question left. The question is what Steve said: In which field extension are the inflection points defined?